# C# How to compare if two variable are the same type?

Tags: c#, types

Would you guys help me out on how to compare if two variable are from the same type in C#? I have searched for this answer for a few days now and all I have found is what I already know: the use of typeof() and object.GetType(). I thought the two working together would manage this but they just don't. Afterwards, looking deeply into the MS docs I understood why(typeof() and a.GetType() return different data) but I will place here what I first tried.

I tried something like:

```
if(varA.GetType() == typeof(varB.GetType()))
{
   //Do something...
}
```

I want something like...

```
if(varB.SameTypeOf(varB)) //In this example returns true because both are type of int
{
    //So something...
}
```

Also, I have tried **System.Type** but it is not what I'm looking for either.

Comment: Why typeof around the GetType? But the real clarification needed here is Why do you need to compare the two types?

Comment: To compare the types of 2 variables, this should work: if (varA.GetType() == varB.GetType()) { .... }. But you should be aware of cases when varA or varB can be null. Also, typeof(varB.GetType()) should be a compile error, so I am not sure I get where you are going with this...

Comment: What about `varA.GetType() == varB.GetType()`?

Comment: @AndreiNeagu To handle null values, it is natural to just say `varA?.GetType() == varB?.GetType()`. If both variables are null, it will be `true`, though.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen We don't know what C# version he is using :) He can be using .NET 1.0 :)

Comment: Thanks everyone, yeah I'm taking care of nulls ... as for why I want to compare two types for, just to know how. :) I feel so stupid to know now that the .GetType() method alone solves the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typeof` is used to get a type object from a type name. In your case you should be able to get by with `a.GetType() == b.GetType()`. Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you might also use `a.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(b.GetType())`.

[`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) has a number of other helpful methods for accomplishing things similar to what you're doing:

- [IsAssignableFrom(Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [IsInstanceOfType(Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [IsSubclassOf(Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: o.O? My god, I was too worried about using typeof() that I didn't even tried  this: 

    a.GetType() == b.GetType()

Thank you Joey!

Comment: You really only need `typeof` when you have a type name and need the `System.Type`  for that, e.g. `typeof(int)`.